# calculate % change in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

```
var current = 12000;
var june = 14600;
var may = 11200;
```

I want percent change with respect to 'current' month parameter. The output should be in percent and it can add or subtract w.r.t. the current month. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple maths:

```
var res=(current-june)/current*100.0;
```

Comment: I think this is backwards. It gives the percentage change of the current value vs. June, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @torazaburo: Agree, if comparing to current, it should be res=(x-curr)/curr, so that when x > curr, then res > 0.

Comment: Right, it's backwards. However, sometimes you need to do it this way. Especially when comparing financial datas, where last quarter is "current" value.

Answer (score 31):

Note that if one of your values is 0 you will get either -100% or Infinity%.
This solves that problem:

```
   function percIncrease(a, b) {
        let percent;
        if(b !== 0) {
            if(a !== 0) {
                percent = (b - a) / a * 100;
            } else {
                percent = b * 100;
            }
        } else {
            percent = - a * 100;            
        }       
        return Math.floor(percent);
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it deals with the edge case scenarios.

Comment: Why have you got `Math.floor` in there?

Comment: @1252748 it's to return the largest integer without any decimals.

Comment: percIncrease(100, 0); // -10000

Answer (score 2):

```
var percentchange = (june - current) / current * 100.0;
```

If your answer is a negative number then this is a percentage increase else decrease.

Comment: I tried with this. http://jsbin.com/vibofaleha/edit?html,js,output. and works perfectly fine..

Comment: Same thing, but I'd prefer to write `(june/current - 1) * 100`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an easy task to handle specials cases, increase or decrease, rounding, over 100%, etc.

```js
function calcPc(n1,n2){
  return (((n2 - n1) / n1 * 100).toLocaleString('fullwide', {maximumFractionDigits:3}) + "%");
}
   
   
   console.log(
   
     " May: "   , calcPc(11200,12000) ,
     "\nJune:" ,  calcPc(14600,12000)
   
   )
```